# How to get the variables that were created inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables

I'm executing javascript files in node.js, and I need to access all the variables that were created in that file. Since these javascript files can hold anything depending on the developer context I need to access the variables programatically.

My question is: How to get the variables that were created inside a function? Something like this:

```
function test(){
    var a = 'hello world';
    var b = 100;
}

console.log(test.variables);
// -> { "a": 'hello world', "b": 100 }
```

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: I'm executing javascript files in node.js, and I need to access all the variables that were created in that file. Since these javascript files can hold anything depending on the developer context I need to access the variables programatically.

Answer (score 4):

No, you need to return those values in an object.

```
function test(){
    var a = 'hello world',
        b = 100;
    return {
      a: a,
      b: b
    };
}

console.log(test); //  { "a": 'hello world', "b": 100 }
```

Or you can save those values to a variable that exists outside of the function scope:

```
var variables = null;
function test(){
    var a = 'hello world',
        b = 100;
    variables = {
      a: a,
      b: b
    };
}
console.log(variables); //  { "a": 'hello world', "b": 100 }
```

Comment: And what if I don't know the name of the variable names? Is there a way to get the variable names programatically from within the function?

Comment: @Adam Not possible. You have to explicitly assign the variables that you want. Either way, you will have to modify the function.

Comment: It's actually possible with `eval` and the `vm` module of node.js, but the problem with eval is that It gets everything from the global context too, but I only need the local context. Almost the same with problem with vm.

Comment: @Adam Not to keen to use `eval`, but that would be your option. Ugly as it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this possible somehow?

No – not without changing the function.

Comment: what do you mean by changing the function?

Comment: I mean literally altering the source code of the function so that it does something different. For instance, sweetamylase's answer demonstrates one viable change.

Comment: and what change would you do?

Comment: It depends on what the goal is. In general there is not a good way to get all of a function's function-scoped variables. The _point_ of scoping is to limit visibility.